# Getting DbContext via Configuration with DbContextOptions

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to get the `DbContext` I registered with options via `services.AddDbContext(...)` on the service provider of the project, but when calling `configuration.Get<ModelContext>` it can not be constructed as the options apparently weren't provided and therefore also no database provider is given.

I am using ASP.NET Core 2.2 with Entity Framework Core 2.2.3 and my `DbContext` is defined in a separate project.

My `DbContext`:

```cs
public class ModelContext : DbContext
{
    public ModelContext(DbContextOptions<ModelContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public ModelContext() { }
}
```

I did not override `OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder)` in `ModelContext`.

```cs
public class StartUp
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        public services.AddEntityFrameworkSqlServer();
        services.AddDbContext<ModelContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(modelConnectionString));
    }
}
```

In the controller (or anywhere really) I call `public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration) => _modelContext = configuration.Get<ModelContext>();` which throws the unexpected exception.

What I specifically get is an `InvalidOperationException` with the message:

> No database provider has been configured for this DbContext. A provider can be configured by overriding the DbContext.OnConfiguring method or by using AddDbContext on the application service provider. If AddDbContext is used, then also ensure that your DbContext type accepts a DbContextOptions object in its constructor and passes it to the base constructor for DbContext.

According to the documentation I read and examples I looked at, the `ModelContext` should be created with the options I defined when calling `AddDbContext<ModelContext>`. Is the `Get` method the wrong one to use?

Comment: `configuration.Get<ModelContext>();`? What's exactly that `configuration` variable? The Controller should expect ModelContext injected into it

Comment: Edited for clarity. `configuration` is an `IConfiguration`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After configuring the db context service in "ConfigureServices" method of the Startup.cs file with something like this :

```
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
services.AddDbContext<BottinContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)) ;
```

Simply add a :

```
ModelContext db
```

parameter to the constructor of your controller and let DI magic happen.

If you've got many controllers and wish to simplify things, you can use a base contructor that holds the db context

```
  public BaseController(ModelContext context /* as well as other injections */)
    {
      _db = context;
    }
    internal ModelContext _db;
```

Comment: Huh works great, thanks! I am probably just blind which is why I didn't find it, but do you by any chance still have a link to the documentation which discusses this feature?

Comment: see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings#aspnet-core

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to get dbContxt instance in a wrong way. Get method is not used to get instance of dbContext object that you registered with dependency injection container.
if you want to get instance of your dbContext class that you registered you can inject it through construction injection for example

```
public class RepositoryWrapper : IRepositoryWrapper
{
        private readonly ModelContext _modelContext;


        public RepositoryWrapper(ModelContext modelContext)
        {
        _modelContext= modelContext;
        }
}
```

is something i am  doing in my project.